# IntentService stop after activity stops

Tags: android, service, media-player, intentservice

I have a simple `activity` which binds a `connection` to a `IntnetService`. The service just plays a `MediaPlayer`. I have implemented `onDestroy` inside the service. However after pressing back in main activity, I was expecting the service to run as usual as IntentService supposes to run in background in separated thread, but after debugging I realized that `onDestory` activity calls in `IntentService` class and destroys the Media Player in it. Where I am wrong probably?

This is my `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private void startAudio() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, PlayerService.class);
        bound = bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
}
```

This is my `Service`:

```
public class PlayerService extends IntentService{
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: try making your service as **STICKY SERVICE**.

Comment: do not extend `IntentService`, use `Service` instead, this is what docs say:  "IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and **stops itself when it runs out of work**."

Comment: I agree with @pskink. Use service instead of IntentService .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bindService is used to bind to service and service stops itself when it has no clients/connections left.Here,as activity is destroyed,service is also getting destroyed

IntentService is supposed to run in background in separated thread until and unless it has work.But here,it is not getting work and hence getting destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Intent service has a queue which queues the incoming intents and performs the actions requested by these intents one by one. Once, the queue of this service is empty i.e. it has completed all of the actions requested by the intents it stops and starts again when it receives another intent.

Since, your service does not have any intent to be processed it ceases to exist. What you need here is a Sticky Service which continues even if it does not have any action to perform.